# 3-Way Relation or Relation with Relation in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I'm puzzling over how to set up this relationship in Laravel, (I'm converting a legacy app):

I have Repair Shops, which provide different types of repairs, on different brands of vehicles.

For example, Shop A might repair Brakes but not Exhaust Systems for Ford vehicles. Shops are required to say what services they provide, (Exhaust repair), but adding a brand is optional. I have `Shop`, `Service`, and `Brand` tables in the DB. Shop and Service have a `belongsToMany` relationship using the `provides_service` pivot table. In the legacy system I have a 3-way pivot table to specify what Services can be done to each Brand in each Shop.

Laravel doesn't seem to do 3-way relationships well, (or does it? If so, point me there!). So, I feel like it would make sense to create a `belongsToMany` between the `provides_service` relation and the `Brand`.  So, is there a way to set up a relationship between a Model and another Relationship in Laravel, or do I have to create a `ProvidesService` model? Creating a `ProvidesService` model seems wasteful, but I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: How about using morphToMany() relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: @MuratTutumlu I checked, but it's not really what I need. There may be a way to make it work, but it would be pretty forced.